# Android - How to retrieve values from SQLite Database and post them as Checkboxes

Tags: android, database, sqlite, checkbox, output

I'm currently trying to retrieve values from my SQLite Database. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUWWE.png)

And output the value of the subname and units on checkboxes. I'm pretty sure I just have to get the IDs so I could output the subname and units values as checkboxes, so subname + unit = 1 checkbox. Could you please provide a sample code or link me a tutorial on how to do this? I'm rather clueless on how to do this and really new to Android.

I'm also looking for a way on how to save their IDs afterwards and add them into another table, so when I retrieve the IDs it will output the values. If you know how to do this too please do help. Thank you! Your time is much appreciated

Currently I have this in my DatabaseHandler.java. I just really don't know the code or syntax on how to retrieve it in my MainActivity and output it on checkboxes.

```js
     //get all subjects
    public List < Subject > getAllSubjects() {

      List < Subject > subjectList = new ArrayList < Subject > ();
      //select all query
      String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SUBJECTS;
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      //loop through all rows and add it to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
          Subject subject = new Subject();
          subject.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
          subject.setSubName(cursor.getString(1));
          subject.setUnits(cursor.getString(2));
          //ADD CONTACT TO LIST
          subjectList.add(subject);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      return subjectList;
    }
```

Comment: You need to watch some tutorials on SQLite databases, but once you retrieve the values, it shouldn't be too hard to create the checkboxes out of them. Go on youtube and type *SQLite tutorial* and start from there.

Comment: @Vucko I totally agree with you but I'm really in a rush, I only have few hours to work on this. And yes, I've been viewing some tutorials but can't find what I need at the moment.

Comment: Well dude I don't wanna sound like your mother, but why'd you leave only a few hours to learn something as challenging as this and to actually use it? If that's already a case, go ask a friend to help you. If you don't have any friends (*who know Android*), go pay someone on UpWork to make that for you for a couple of bucks. This is everything that comes to my mind. Gotta think on your feet mate.